# React <Link to...> when table row is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple table, and I need to Link to another component, when a row is clicked. Right now I have one column of clickable data in the table. Is it possible to do it in a simple way? I have tried different ways to solve this task, but seems like most of the answers are already outdated...
This is what I have:

```
<tbody>
            {this.state.users.map((user, id) => {
                return (                    
                    <tr key={ user.id }>
                        <td><Link to={`/user/${user.id}`}>{ user.id }</Link></td>
                        <td>{ user.first_name }</td> 
                        <td>{ user.last_name }</td> 
                        <td>{ user.email }</td>
                        <td>{ user.gender }</td>
                        <td>{ user.ip_address }</td>
                        <td>{ this.state.total_clicks[user.id] }</td>
                        <td>{ this.state.total_page_views[user.id] }</td>
                    </tr>                             
                )           
            })}
          </tbody>
```

This is what I want:

```
<tbody>
            {this.state.users.map((user, id) => {
                return (
                    <Link to={`/user/${user.id}`}>                  
                        <tr key={ user.id }>
                            <td>{ user.id }</td>
                            <td>{ user.first_name }</td> 
                            <td>{ user.last_name }</td> 
                            <td>{ user.email }</td>
                            <td>{ user.gender }</td>
                            <td>{ user.ip_address }</td>
                            <td>{ this.state.total_clicks[user.id] }</td>
                            <td>{ this.state.total_page_views[user.id] }</td>
                        </tr>
                    </Link>                           
                )           
            })}
          </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

but to do this, you need to setup a `onClick` handler on the `tr` component. Which means the page change can be done only programmatically and not via a component like Link.

I assume you use `react-router-dom`. To do this, you need to put the `withRouter` HOC on your table. Then you have access to the `history` prop which lets you do a `history.push('/new-url')`.

Gathering all things together it gives this :

```
const MyComponent = ({history}) => {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {this.state.users.map((user, id) => (
        <tr key={ user.id } onClick={() => history.push(`/user/${user.id}`)}>
          /* stuff */
        </tr>                             
      )}
    </tbody>
  )
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

Comment: I used it like this, and it worked: `<tr key={ user.id } onClick={() => this.props.history.push(`/user/${user.id}`)}>` Thanks a lot:)